# How to finds users that can access a particular table?

Tags: oracle

How do I find all the users that can access one particular table?

For example table 'Table01'

Thanks

Comment: In general, this is hard.  You can have privileges granted to you.  You can have privileges granted to a role that you have.  That role might be password protected, though, and you don't have the password.  That role might be a non-defalult role that may or may not be available to a particular session.  You can have access through system privileges.  And you can have roles within roles.

Comment: I would probably at least start with Pete Finnigan's "who_can_access" script.  http://www.petefinnigan.com/who_can_access.sql  from his tools page http://www.petefinnigan.com/tools.htm .  That runs to 400 lines and doesn't check every possible permutation but it's a good start.  A generic answer would need to know things like whether you want to consider a password-protected non-default role the same as a direct object grant, ignore it, or add it to a list of "people who may have access depending on what else they know".  Then there are things like proxy users and other avenues like views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sys user then you can use `dba_tab_privs` view as shown below.

```
SQL>Conn / as sysdba
SQL>select grantee, table_name, privilege from dba_tab_privs where table_name='Table01';
```

Update:

As [Justin Cave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/555/justin-cave) and [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) said, its a bit complex to get the accurate result from general `dba_` or `role_` views.

Though you can query `role_tab_privs` to get all the roles and its object privileges.

```
SQL> select grantee,  privilege from dba_tab_privs where table_name='EMPLOYEES' and owner='HR';

GRANTEE                        PRIVILEGE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
SCOTT                          SELECT
OE                             SELECT
OE                             REFERENCES
JAY                            UPDATE
R1                             SELECT
```

In the above result Grantee `R1` is a role which has `SELECT` object privilege on `EMPLOYEES` table.

Here is a useful post similar to this. [oracle - list users with access to certain tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/oracle-list-users-with-access-to-certain-tables)

Comment: This would only return users who were granted access directly, but not those who can access the table via a role.

Comment: mustaccio, then what query would you use to display both?